# Use SQL Cursor or any other suggestions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Trying to find a solution.
I have to create a a list of records using this criteria:

Record starts with Active Status and Start Date from Main table.
Second table has Status (Active/Inactive) and Status change date.

I have to find any record with this criteria:  the record was Inactive for 1 year or more and then became Active again.

I was trying to build a view but it did work only for records with few Status changes.
I was trying the cursor but looks like I need help there.

here is the sample Status change data for 1 record:

```
Inactive   10/19/2016
Active     11/2/2016
Inactive   9/12/2017
Active     9/15/2017
Inactive   1/19/2018
Active     11/22/2019
Inactive   3/1/2020
Active     4/5/2020
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a view where each row has the ‘from’ & ‘to’ statuses and dates, eg with cols `Id, StartStatus, StartStatusDate  , EndStatus, EndStatusDate, Duration`. To do this you’ll have to join the history table to itself, looking for the previous status record. Then it becomes much easier to query that view, since it’s presenting the data how you want to think about it.

Eg

```
select * from MyView
where Duration > 365
and StartStatus = ‘Inactive’
and EndStatus = ‘Active’
```

Comment: Thank you.   I will try to figure this out.

Comment: I was not able to find a way to follow your advice. Can you, please, provide more details?
Thank you

Comment: As @dalek suggested, try expanding your question to include more details and show what you’ve tried, even if it’s not working it helps us see what you’re having problems with.